# Using the fix() or edit() function to alter another function in R

Tags: r, edit

I am trying to edit a function in R, the function is in a package called 'TwoSampleMR', the function itself is called 'forest_plot_1_to_many', the function plots a forest plot of multilple exposures against an outcome.

I want to change the size of the text within the plot, unfortunately the font size is pre set and cannot be edited the when the function is called. Therefore, I am trying to edit the function itself. A  lot of articles say use
**trace()** but this confuses me and i don't think it's what i'm looking for as I'm not fixing  and error in the code, im just changing it.

one article I saw said use **fix()** or **edit()** fot edit the function, so I try:
    fix(fores_plot_1_to_many)

and got the edit pop up as a result, i make the adjustment - 'size=10' to 'size=15'.

but then the function doesn't work at all with an error:

> could not find function "forest_plot_names2"

my question is can **fix()** and **edit()** be used to alter functions?

## workable example:

```
install_github('MRCIEU/TWOSampleMR')
library(TwoSampleMR)
library(cowplot)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
#you then need data formated like this(use dget):
```

> structure(list(id.exposure = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "100", 
>   "104", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "72", "72", "72", "72", "72", 
>   "999", "999", "999", "999", "999"), id.outcome = c("7", "7", 
>   "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", 
>   "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7"), outcome = structure(c(1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Coronary heart disease || id:7", class = "factor"), 
>       exposure = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
>       4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Adiponectin || id:1", 
>       "Hip circumference || id:100", "Waist circumference || id:104", 
>       "Body mass index || id:2", "Waist-to-hip ratio || id:72", 
>       "Body fat || id:999"), class = "factor"), method = structure(c(2L, 
>       5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
>       6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 6L), .Label = c("Inverse variance weighted", 
>       "MR Egger", "Simple mode", "Wald ratio", "Weighted median", 
>       "Weighted mode"), class = "factor"), nsnp = c(14, 14, 14, 
>       14, 14, 2, 1, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 
>       10, 10, 10, 10), b = c(-0.117626170585508, -0.0897929616150017, 
>       -0.0859881930532524, -0.0481657038212953, -0.0924464446740587, 
>       -0.186310066104502, -0.446296296296296, 0.502493509729729, 
>       0.387006481544447, 0.445909096953398, 0.34015542866459, 0.388824880964004, 
>       0.319237123956867, 0.440777466374666, 0.479474060003586, 
>       0.613267898718917, 0.539371930718197, -0.099234917723361, 
>       0.492007216440334, 0.266451632000445, 0.625148495006193, 
>       0.584255954193752), se = c(0.099327158876229, 0.052718121960683, 
>       0.0701141773426372, 0.0805966230812049, 0.0480249872448083, 
>       0.212900382630982, 0.348251851851852, 0.143960561723383, 
>       0.073084143930427, 0.0589830187629256, 0.159504867346875, 
>       0.103010766708134, 0.670839958692018, 0.130066610555476, 
>       0.147334903140841, 0.314200209490734, 0.220010589431754, 
>       1.62221372607913, 0.165297837802832, 0.329449407451525, 0.239252578485129, 
>       0.171657887534756), pval = c(0.259248511221647, 0.0885183822967944, 
>       0.220047295734388, 0.560363740959668, 0.0763956662641734, 
>       0.381517091710096, 0.200006460243279, 0.000801258991849775, 
>       1.18785466550157e-07, 4.03202032734861e-14, 0.0361057370718699, 
>       0.000310917456068699, 0.637854263026472, 0.000701839665612893, 
>       0.00113666506799647, 0.0606742038535203, 0.0204847853665443, 
>       0.952722454601399, 0.00291569423908827, 0.418642505104635, 
>       0.0281355793252735, 0.00782847174837027)), .Names = c("id.exposure", 
>   "id.outcome", "outcome", "exposure", "method", "nsnp", "b", "se", 
>   "pval"), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")

```
#once you have the data saved as a dataframe you can use 
res1<-subset_on_method(res1)
res1<-sort_1_to_many(res1,b="b",sort_action=4)
forest_plot_1_to_many(res1,b="b",se="se",
                       exponentiate=F,ao_slc=F,lo=NULL,up=NULL,
                       TraitM="exposure",col1_width=1.3,by=NULL,
                       trans="identity",xlab= "(95% confidence interval)",
                       addcols=c("nsnp","b","se","pval"),addcol_widths=c(0.6,1.1,1.1,1.1),
                       addcol_titles=c("No.SNPs","Beta", "se","P-val")  
)  
#this will give a goo looking forest plot, you can then try edit the function using fix() or edit()
fix(forest_plot_1_to_many)
## OR 
var1 <- edit(forest_plot_1_to_many)
```

hope that works :) 
thanks

Comment: @user2554330 ok I 've edited my question now, but after trying ista's solution I dont think that I am able to chenge the font size in of the function, i found a different solutio now, thanks anyway

Comment: @user2554330 are you able to change to font size of the contents of the plot? and if so how?

Comment: Ye that what i did but it has no effect on the end result, and I don't have ample R knowledge to know where else to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because `forest_plot_1_to_many` uses the unexported `forest_plot_names2` function. Because `forest_plot_1_to_many` is in the `TwoSampleMR` namespace, it can 'see' other function in that namespace, even if they are not exported. <del>When you copy the function to your global environment</del> If you change the function's environment it can no longer 'see' those unexported functions. This is true <del>if you use `fix`, or</del> if you simply print the function and copy/paste/edit/evaluate it manually.

For a quick-and-dirty work-around, you can use `:::` to call unexported functions. When you `fix` `forest_plot_1_to_many` replace all calls to `forest_plot_names2` with `TwoSampleMR:::forest_plot_names2`. More complicated things are possible with e.g., `fixInNamespace` but I don't have much experience with that.

Comment: quick and dirty is what i'm looking for lol,  thanks this worked

Comment: @user2554330 thank you for the corrections, I will update the answer.